# Google Channel API sending message with token

Tags: google-app-engine, token, channel-api

In documents it says 'client_id' part can actually be the token, however it doesn't work. Anyone know why?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/functions

> If the client_id parameter is actually a token returned by a create_channel call then send_message can be used for different versions of the app. For instance you could create the channel on the front end and then send messages from a backend of the app.

the reason i want to use this, is because i want to send messages to anonymous users as well, without requiring them to login. i don't know if it is possible to assign them a 'client_id' if token doesn't work.

this is how i am creating the token

```
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        token = channel.create_channel(user.user_id())
    else:
        token = channel.create_channel(str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

then injecting into client

```
template_values = {
        'token' : token,
    }
```

on the client side open the channel

```
      openChannel = function() {
    var token = '{{ token }}';
    var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
    var handler = {
      'onopen': onOpened,
      'onmessage': onMessage,
      'onerror': function() {},
      'onclose': function() {}
    };
    var socket = channel.open(handler);
    socket.onopen = onOpened;
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
  }
```

now send a message

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', path, true);
xhr.send();
```

in the server,
when the message is received send back a message using the token

```
channel.send_message(token, someMessage)
```

back to client

```
onMessage = function(m) {
alert("you have some message");     
}
```

this sequence works fine if client_id() is used instead of token when calling send_message

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. What doesn't work? How does it not work? What behavior do you expect, what behavior do you actually see?

Comment: @Amber well i am expecting the same behavior as using client_id. when i call channel.send_message(token, message) with the token created before, in the client side basically i dont receive any message. on the other hand using client_id, i can receive the message that i sent.

Comment: Try showing some code for how you're generating the token and passing it around, then.

Comment: @amber added what i am doing in the question

Comment: Where are you storing the token between requests?

Comment: @amber i made it global. probably not a good way but it should work i think

Comment: @btevfik I am not even to create channel first time. Can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332222/unable-to-create-new-channel-in-javascript-of-channel-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you actually have a problem here.

You are able to send messages to users that are logged in or not.

The problem you are having I think is knowing that there are multiple ways to use the channel API re: tokens.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview#Life_of_a_Typical_Channel_Message

> In this example, it shows the JavaScript client explicitly requests a token and sends its Client ID to the server. In contrast, you could choose to design your application to inject the token into the client before the page loads in the browser, or some other implementation if preferred.

[image: Option 1]

> This diagram shows the creation of a channel on the server. **In this
>   example, it shows the JavaScript client explicitly requests a token
>   and sends its Client ID to the server.** In contrast, you could choose
>   to design your application to inject the token into the client before
>   the page loads in the browser, or some other implementation if
>   preferred.

Here's my demo implementation, hope it helps somehow: https://github.com/Paul1234321/channelapidemo.git

Here's the code for creating the channel on GAE:

```
  client_id = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-",'')
  channel_token = channel.create_channel(client_id)
```

And in the JS:

```
channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{ token }}');
```

Have a look at it in action: http://pppredictor.appspot.com/

Comment: logged in or not, i am not able to send messages using a token. client_id seems like it comes from only logged in users. unless there is a way to assign unique client_ids to anonymous users. i dont think the implementation of explicitly requesting a token vs injecting a token makes any difference.

Comment: The channel API is nothing to do with if users are logged in or not, as you can see from my demo. I suspect that non-alphanumeric characters in the UUID you are generating might be the problem, try stripping them out? The tokens are used to create the channel, not send messages. The javascript needs the token to create the channel, you send the messages with the client id.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a suggestion to strip out the - from the UUID.

Comment: ok thanks. so you cannot send a message with tokens even though it says you can in the documentation

Comment: Yeah, you create the channel with tokens and send messages with the id.

Comment: This problem was also bothering me for a while.... Just confirming that using GAE 1.7.6 and channel.send_message() doesn't work with a token, only a client_id.

Answer (score 1):

In response to btevfik's initial question: Allowing tokens or client_id in send_message is a feature released in 1.7.5 (very recently). Some people may not be familiar with it yet so therefore they suggest to use client_id. Both should work!

The only thing that I can see in your code is the fact that you should not rely on token variable to be correct in between two requests. They may not even land on the same instance of the app. If you share your code with more details I may be able to spot something. The proper way would be to either store the token in the datastore or pass it from the client as a parameter when you send the message that will trigger a message back.

The purpose of this feature was to allow people to send messages from backends (or other versions). Before was not possible whereas now you can do it if you use directly the tokens instead of the client_id.

Comment: thanks for your reply. since i couldn't get my app to send message with tokens earlier, i used the client_id's instead. it is working fine right now. for logged in users, it is easy to send a message because all you need to do is to get the current user's user id, however for anonymous users, since i am assigning them an arbitrary client_id, it was not as easy, so now i am storing this client id in a cookie where it can be retrieved. when i have time i will probably go over the code again. and ask any more questions if have. thanks again

Comment: the app is at http://chatter-now.appspot.com and the src code is at https://github.com/btevfik/chatter-webapp

Answer (score 1):

Long time this post has been around, but just curious about your usage of the token global variable?

I don't see this code:

```
global token
```

before you set the token

```
user = users.get_current_user()

if user:
    token = channel.create_channel(user.user_id())
else:
    token = channel.create_channel(str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

If that code is missing, then `token` will be set in the local scope of the function above and not globally. So, the token value used later will be `None` (or to what ever the token was initialised with.)

Just a thought, if its still relevant.

Comment: i just checked the code. and i guess you are right. it doesnt have `global`. i dont know why i didnt see it. this was just a little project for my self to try out app engine. assigning global to token might solve my initial problem, but haven't actually tried it out. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store request-specific values in global variables. Store them in a cookie or pass them as a request parameter instead.

Comment: would that change the outcome though?